# NGINX reverse proxy with registered domain name not working (cannot call API)

Tags: docker, api, nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

Nginx version 1.14.0

nginx.conf file (the "fake" domain below is officially registered):

```
http {

    #default stuff...
       
       include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
       include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    
       server {
         listen 80;
         server_name mydomain.registered.com;
         
         location / {
             proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
             #I also tried with the server's actual IP
             #I also tried with or without the slash at the end
         }
       }
       
       #default stuff...
}
```

Assuming a "fake" IP of the server being `10.70.0.65`, my APIs are:

```
http://10.70.0.65:8001/auth/login
http://10.70.0.65:8001/auth/logout
etc...
```

My above API server is a running docker container with port mapping as below:

```
0.0.0.0:8000-8001->8000-8001/tcp, :::8000-8001->8000-8001/tcp
```

When calling the APIs directly using the server's IP, e.g. `http://10.70.0.65:8001/auth/login`, it works. But calling using the domain name, e.g. `http://mydomain.registered.com/auth/login`, does not work.

How can I make it works?

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass `Host:` header to your backend:

```
     location / {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001/;
         proxy_set_header Host      $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     }
```